# Doctrine ORM Error

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

**ContextErrorException:**

**Catchable Fatal Error:** Argument 1 passed to Sonata\EasyExtendsBundle\Mapper\DoctrineORMMapper::loadClassMetadata() must be an instance of Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Event\LoadClassMetadataEventArgs, instance of Doctrine\ORM\Event\LoadClassMetadataEventArgs given

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "2.3.*",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "1.3.2",
        "sonata-project/user-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/datagrid-bundle": "~2.2@dev",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "2.3.*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.3-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Must ask question! Must make readable! Must make objective/problem clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your use statements in the class where you're getting the exception, try replacing `use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LoadClassMetadataEventArgs;` with `use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Event\LoadClassMetadataEventArgs;`, or try digging around with a debugger.

Answer (score 4):

Edit:
This is now fixed in the 2.1.9 version ([source](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataEasyExtendsBundle/commit/fb8c1335e3fcf4791fffd13d63b80741445c5665)).

---

There was a commit in the EasyExtends bundle ([source](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataEasyExtendsBundle/commit/86e6daa00da960d81c620503969cd6b50309ea35)) that seems to have caused this.

My suggestion is to add an explicit version in your composer.json file for the time being. The version I got this error in is 2.1.8, so I used the version before that commit:

```
"sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "2.1.7"
```

Comment: They added it back in for 2.1.10 ([source](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataEasyExtendsBundle/blob/2.1.10/Mapper/DoctrineORMMapper.php))